The program window does not appear and the console is empty PyQt6
I have a problem opening a file with Qt Designer. When I try to open a program without a class, everything is fine, but when I try to open a program with a class, the program works, but nothing is displayed in the console and the program does not open.
Please help me.
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.window = loader.load('project2.ui', None)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

The above program doesn't work, but the one below does.
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

loader = QUiLoader()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = loader.load('project2.ui', None)
window.show()

app.exec()



self.window is just a reference with absolutely no relation with the actual window being shown, which is therefore empty. Check the duplicated answers to understand how to properly use QUiLoader.

Firstly, you may be running into the issue reported in this question. Secondly, if the ui file contains a QMainWindow class, you cannot easily create a subclass from it when using PySide. For a work-around, see this answer.
